# Why is a WatchKit SpriteKit scene frozen after the phone/watch receive a call or message?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, watchkit

If the watch app interface use a WKInterfaceSKScene, it get frozen after the watch has switched to display the incoming call/message screen.

I spent two days looking at my code to find the reason and the solution to this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The WKInterfaceSKScene object has a paused property. It is set to true automatically by the system on incoming call and probably any other automatic application switch.

The solution is simply to ensure that your interface controller willActivate method reset this property:

```
wkscene.paused = NO;
```